# how to delete Parent table without removing children table content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to delete Parent Table with all table attribute, without removing children table using jquery/javascript

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Data</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td><td>B</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Output::

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take inner table with `unwrap` and change html of parent element `body` in this case which will delete old table.

```js
$('body').html($('table table').unwrap())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you can take inner table, delete old one and then add inner table to parent element.

```js
var table = $('table table').unwrap();
$('table').remove()

$('body').html(table)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```